# Are questions about the legitimacy specific QA job postings appropriate?

Tags: discussion

[question if this job should be a red flag or not](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7029/question-if-this-job-should-be-a-red-flag-or-not)

While the job described is regarding software QA, the tone of the title and question lean towards asking if the job posting is legitimate or a scam. This seems more opinion orientated, and I'm not sure if red-lining job postings helps educate the community on QA and testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the job being software QA makes it on topic for this site. The job could be filleting fish, and the question would be the same - is it legit, etc?

This particular question looks off-topic to me on at least a couple of counts:

1. The content isn't particularly about software testing.
2. It's too localised - it's about one specific job posting, not about trends.
3. Asking for opinions.

In the more general case, I would say that I would be surprised if a question about a specific QA job posting didn't fall under one of the above. I can think of some questions you might ask about recruiting/looking for roles that would be of general interest to the community, but I honestly can't think of a way a posting about a specific role is going to be of interest to anyone except the poster.